# Flash Player Debugger ActiveX for IE is not working

Tags: debugging, apache-flex

Although I have never worked with Flex before, I have to do some changes in a Flex application. When I install ordinary Flash Player from http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/ I can open the application in IE and it works correctly. However, when I install the Flash Player Debugger ActiveX for IE from http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html and open the page in IE then I get the following error message:

```
Alternate HTML content should be placed here. This content requires the Adobe Flash Player. Get Flash
```

I need to use the Debugger version in order to be able to debug the application in IntelliJ. What could be possibly wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that you can only use the Debugger version of the ActiveX Flash Player plugin with the 32-bit IE version.